# Global variables in multiples functions in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, import, global

i will try to explain my situation with examples:

Im using global to declare a variable but this work only in a function, when i try to another sub function doesnt work.

register.py

```
def main():
    alprint = input("Enter something: ")
    if alprint == "a":
        def alCheck():
            global CheckDot
            CheckDot = input("Enter your opinion: ")
        def alTest():
            global CheckTest
            CheckTest = input("Hope it works: ")
        alCheck()
        alTest()
main()
```

and content.py

```
from register import CheckTest

if CheckTest == "ad":
    print("You are welcome!")
```

When i declare this variable checkTest in a sub function(function, alTest()) of main, using global and importing to another file, it doesnt work, i tried a lot of things, but nothing.

Comment: I think you have other problems than global variables here (they are usually a bad idea anyway). Move those two function definitions out of the if clause. Instead of global variables, use ``return``.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you give me a simple idea or example?

Comment: Well, I would but it's quite unclear what you are trying to build in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It *would* work, except that if the user enters something other than `a` for the first `input`, `CheckTest` is not defined, so it gives an `ImportError`. You might want to try something like this instead:

```
def main():
    global CheckTest, CheckDot
    def alCheck():
        global CheckDot
        CheckDot = input("Enter your opinion: ")
    def alTest():
        global CheckTest
        CheckTest = input("Hope it works: ")
    alprint = input("Enter something: ")
    if alprint == "a":
        alCheck()
        alTest()
    else:
        CheckTest = None
        CheckDot = None
main()
```

This way, `CheckTest`, and `CheckDot` are always defined.